# Autowiring main class in Swing/Spring App

Tags: java, spring, swing, autowired

My main class is:
    package net.draconia;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import net.draconia.apigenerator.ui.APIGeneratorFrame;

public class APIGenerator implements Runnable, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3837819659124519652L;

    @Autowired
    private APIGeneratorFrame mWndView;

    public APIGenerator()
    { }

    protected APIGeneratorFrame getView()
    {
        return(mWndView);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
            {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());

            getView().setVisible(true);
            }
        catch(Exception objException)
            {
            objException.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] sArrArgs)
    {
        ApplicationContext objContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");

        try
            {
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)(objContext)).registerShutdownHook();

            APIGenerator objGenerator = ((APIGenerator)(objContext.getBean("app")));

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(objGenerator);
            }
        finally
            {
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)(objContext)).close();
            }
    }
}
```

For all intents and purposes let's assume APIGeneratorFrame is just:

```
public class APIGeneratorFrame extends JFrame
{ }
```

My simplified application-context.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

    <bean class="net.draconia.apigenerator.ui.APIGeneratorFrame" />

    <bean class="net.draconia.APIGenerator" id="app" />
</beans>
```

When I run the application though - I get a null for the view.  I've been doing Spring for several years and in the past I used lazy creation(if(mWndView == null) mWndView = ... return mWndView) or made the getters and setters for the View to be public, and added references inside application-context - both which got me around this issue but I'm trying with this project to rely more on Spring and there's really no reason to make the View public as it shouldn't ever be accessed publicly outside of the main class which is more of a springboard to the main event.

What might I be doing wrong that View is not being autowired?  As you can see I grab the main application from the application context file so it's managed by spring.  I haven't tested the View class but right now all it contains is a label and a list, not even accessing them yet but autowired and defined in the app context file as well.  I can include a more complete app context and/or APIGeneratorFrame class if necessary.  I tried to include just the simplest though for the time being.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Autowiring main class -- > Sounds awful :)

Comment: Why?  The rest is autowired.  Spring takes care of determining if some required component is instantiated or whatever, making sure it's not null.  In general this reduces the size of methods - I could potentially split the main class into a main class and the controller but I've always combined the 2 of them and the Controller would have the view in it - That would solve my problem I'm **almost** certain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried giving the view bean an id?

```
<bean id="mWndView" class="net.draconia.apigenerator.ui.APIGeneratorFrame" />
```

Further remarks:

@Autowired is a Spring specific annotation, the more general one is @Inject.

The return(mWndView); statement does not need the brackets.

You could use the component-scan tag from "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" instead of manual wiring:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.draconia" />
```

To use the component-scan you can omit the beans in your current context and add @Component annotations on the classes.

Comment: I haven't found anything telling me exactly what @Component does outside of an Spring-MVC setting - what does it do?

Since posting, I have tried adding an id as well as splitting the Controller interface off from the main class - just moved the NPE to the Controller class - not autowiring the view there either.  

What do you mean omit the beans in the current context?    How would Spring know what to send to constructors and set property values to?

Comment: Just tried @Component and removing at least App, Controller, and View and got the error that no bean named controller was found - I'm not sure of a way to get the bean out and start spring without ApplicationContext.getBean(...)

Comment: Ok I did the component-scan - at first because I had the components in, it said there were duplicate choices for beans to autowire - removed the @Component annotations and it started up without a hitch - Thank you Adriaan - I put a checkmark - I'd upvote it but it wouldn't let me saying I needed 15 reputation - I haven't answered many questions on here - but Thank you very much!